# What's the difference between ∀x(P(x)) and ∀xP(x)?

Tags: predicate-logic

Edit: Changed logically equivalent to logically implies! Sorry. Also realized removing the context when trying to understand something is a bad idea.

Just started learning predicate logic.

What I'm trying to prove is that `∀x∃y( P(x)->Q(y) )` is logically Implies to `( ∀xP(x) ) -> ( ∃yQ(y) )`.

I know that `∀x∃y( P(x)->Q(y) )` is satisfied whenever P(x) is false or Q(y) is true (based on the truth table for implies).

And `( ∀xP(x) ) -> ( ∃yQ(y) )` is satisfied whenever  `( ∀xP(x) )` is false or `( ∃yQ(y) )` is true.

But I need a better understanding of the difference between `∀x(P(x))` and `∀xP(x)`.

Question 1: What does `∀x(P(x))` mean? What I thought was that it means "for any element x in the domain, P(x) is true". Doesn't this mean `∀x(P(x))` is Always satisfied?

Question 2: What does `∀xP(x)` mean? I thought this also means "for any element x in the domain, P(x) is true".

Note: I was given the answer to this proof, and it states that `∀x∃y( P(x)->Q(y) )` is satisfied when "for any element x, P(x) is falsified" and `( ∀xP(x) ) -> ( ∃yQ(y) )` is satisfied when "for Some element x, P(x) is falsified".

But as mentioned, I'm having difficulty understanding what the formulas  mean and how they are different.

Comment: They are the same, the one with more parentheses is just a little bit more specific.

Comment: @Ian so what does "∀xP(x)" mean? It doesnt mean "for any element x in the domain, P(x) holds true" because the proof answer states that the formula satisfies whenever "∀xP(x)" is falsified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid there's quite a bit of confusion going on here. So let me try to address not only your two actual questions, but also some other issues that I see here.

**[1]** Generally  speaking, parentheses in logical expressions are used in the same way and for the same purpose as in arithmetical expressions: to show order of operations, or so to speak to show which things go together and which don't. So the answer to the question in your title:

> What's the difference between $\forall x(P(x))$ and $\forall xP(x)$?

is that there's no difference, as they mean exactly the same thing: for all values of $x$ (in the given domain or universe) $P(x)$ is true. (Note that this also covers both your Questions 1 and 2.) But...

**[2]** Taking things out of context is extremely dangerous!!! If someone asks you:

> What's the difference between $2+3$ and $(2+3)$?

anybody will say that they are the same thing, both equal to $5$... Until it turns out that they were taken from longer expressions $\color{green}{2+3\cdot4}$ and $\color{blue}{(2+3)\cdot4}$, where presence or absence of parentheses makes a whole lot of difference!

**[3]** And that's why the actual question in the body of your post hardly has anything to do with what you asked in the title. According to your post, you're

> trying to prove is that $\forall x\, \exists y\, (P(x)\to Q(y))$ is logically equivalent to $(\forall x\, P(x))\to(\exists y\,Q(y))$.

Note that while $\forall xP(x)$ is the antecedent of the second formula, $\forall x(P(x))$ does not appear anywhere in either of them. So when you used it in the title, where did it come from?

**[4]** Moreover, these two statements actually are **NOT** equivalent to each other. Here's a quick counterexample. Let the domain be all integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Let

$$P(x)=[x\text{ is even}] \quad \text{and} \quad Q(y)=[y+1<y].$$

(I'm using brackets as quotation marks.) Then:

- $\forall x\, \exists y\, (P(x)\to Q(y))$ is *false*. It requires that for any $x$ there exists some $y$ such that $P(x)\to Q(y)$. But if $x=2$, then $P(2)\to Q(y)$ doesn't hold for any $y$, because $P(2)$ is true and $Q(y)$ is false for any $y$.
- But $(\forall x\, P(x))\to(\exists y\,Q(y))$ is *true*, because the antecedent $\forall x\, P(x)$ is false.

So if you have been given an exercise where two statements are given and your task is to prove that they are logically equivalent, then maybe you made a typo somewhere?

Comment: Good catch! Had to show ∀x∃y( P(x)->Q(y) ) logically Implies the other formula, not equivalent. Learned a lot from your post though and proving they arent equivalent definitely helped better my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: I actually didn't understand the difference between the two formulas. I saw that the two formulas place the brackets differently, so I thought I could simplify the first formula by removing the "there exists y" part and first understanding what "∀x(P(x))" means (∀x∃y( P(x)-> without the "there exists").

Comment: @user2719875: Glad I could help! I hope you see now that `removing the "there exists y" part` was not a good idea. :-) Just like there's no "$2+3$" in $2+3\cdot4$, there's no "$\forall x\,(P(x))$" in $\forall x\, \exists y\, (P(x)\to Q(y))$.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have the two different cases i) $\forall x, P (x) \rightarrow  \exists y: Q (y)$ and  ii)  $(\forall x, P (x))\rightarrow \exists y:Q (y)$.  These are clearly different,  as the *if* parts are different  (have different truth value definitions).  In general $P (x) $ being true for all x is *different* than for all x,  if $P (x) $ is true,  then such and such.  The former condition is false when $\exists x:P (x)$ is false.  But in this case,  there may be other x such that P (x) is true.   So in ii), the conditional is true because your if part is false.   In i), you still need to check whether when $P (x) $ is true,  the conclusion  $(\exists y:Q (y))$ is false or not...
**Correction**  Yes, I have seen your edit, they are not equivalent. ..in the situation I referred to ii) can be true while i) is false

Comment: I read your answer a couple times and the difference between the two finally are making more sense to me. Thanks! I was getting confused here: When I read your case (i) out loud, I read it as `for all x, if P(x) then such and such`. But when you say  "But in general P(x) being true for all x is different than `for all x, if P(x) is true, then such and such.`" you are referring to case (ii) right?

Comment: Oh and secondly, when you say "In i), you still need to check whether when P(x) is true, the conclusion (∃y:Q(y)) is false or not...". In (ii), don't I Also need to do the same? i.e check whether when P(x) is true, the conclusion (∃y:Q(y)) is false or not? Because if the conclusion is false, then it is `if True -> then False` which results in the entire statement (ii) being false, right?

Comment: @user2719875 well,  i was assuming we had at least one x such that p (x) is false; making  $\forall x, P (x) $ false. ..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some additional parentheses will help.  But [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385019/whats-the-difference-between-%E2%88%80xpx-and-%E2%88%80xpx#comment4918108_2385043) makes me think one more thing would be helpful : tracking when a variable depends on another.  One of your sentences has a dependency and the other doesn't so this is another way to see that there could be some difference between them.

The sentence $$ \forall x \exists y \left( \strut{} P(x) \implies Q(y) \right)$$ could be additionally parenthesized as $$ \forall x \left( \strut{} \exists y \left( \strut{} P(x) \implies Q(y) \right) \right)  \text{.}$$  Let us use subscripts to indicate dependence, for instance "$y_x$" means that the choice of $y$ depends on the choice of $x$ (in the sense that a different choice of $x$ could necessitate a different choice of $y$.  Notice that "$\exists y (\dots)$" appears inside the universal quantification of $x$.  This means that for each choice of $x$ there exists some $y$ (perhaps depending on $x$) such that ... .  So we have $$ \forall x (\exists y_x ( P(x) \implies Q(y_x) ))  \text{.}$$  In words:  for any $x$ at all, there exists a $y$ (perhaps depending on $x$) such that $P(x)$ being true implies $Q(y)$ is also true.

Your other sentence is $$(\forall x P(x)) \implies (\exists y Q(y))$$ which we could additionally parenthesize as $$(\forall x (P(x))) \implies (\exists y (Q(y)))  \text{.}$$  But this time, the choice of $y$ is not permitted to depend on $x$ because "$\exists y$" does not appear in the elliptic subexpression of "$\forall x (\dots)$".  That is, there is no relationship between the variables $x$ and $y$.  In words: if $P(x)$ happens to be true for every possible choice of $x$, then there is at least one choice of $y$ making $Q(y)$ true.